# not displaying friend requests on friends requests fragment kotlin-firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

[image]
The problem is that i want to display all friends requests in a fragment called FriendsFragment.This fragment calls an Adapter Class containing an internal class called ViewHolder.
But the Friends requests are not showing. And a message in the logcat always is shown "No adapter attached;skipped Layout" .What is the problem?

here is the code of my fragment called FriendsFragment:

```
class FriendsFragment : Fragment() {
    private  var recyclerView1: RecyclerView?=null
    private  var recyclerView2: RecyclerView?=null
    private  var mUsers:MutableList<Users>?=null
    private var friendAdapter:FriendAdapter?=null
    private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
    private var currentState:String?=""
    private var firebaseUserId:String=""

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false)

        recyclerView1=view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_requests)
        recyclerView1?.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView1?.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(context)

        recyclerView2=view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_Friends)
        recyclerView2?.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView2?.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(context)
        mUsers=ArrayList()
        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        firebaseUserId=mAuth.currentUser!!.uid
        val usersRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://online-chat-541f3-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com").reference.child("Users")
        val requestRef =
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://online-chat-541f3-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com").reference.child(
                "Friends Requests"
            )

        usersRef.addValueEventListener(object:ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                mUsers?.clear()
                    for (snapshot in p0.children) {
                        val users: Users? = snapshot.getValue(Users::class.java)
                        if (!(users!!.getUid()).equals(firebaseUserId) && users != null) {
                            if(p0.child(firebaseUserId).child(users.getUid().toString()).child("request_type").value=="received" &&
                                p0.child(users.getUid().toString()).child(firebaseUserId).child("request_type").value=="sent"
                                    ) {

                                mUsers?.add(users)
                                friendAdapter =
                                    context?.let {
                                        FriendAdapter(
                                            it,
                                            mUsers as ArrayList<Users>,
                                            false
                                        )
                                    }
                                friendAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                                recyclerView1!!.adapter = friendAdapter
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            }
        })

        return view
    }
}
```

The recycler view for showing Friends requests is recyclerView1.
Also this the xml code of the layout attached to the View Holder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/friendsProfileResource"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/username"
            >
        </de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/usernameFriendsResource"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/friendsProfileResource"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:text="Username"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            >
        </TextView>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/online_status_img"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/online"
            android:layout_below="@id/usernameFriendsResource"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/last_message_friends_ressource"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/usernameFriendsResource"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/friendsProfileResource"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:text="last message"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            >
        </TextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/accept_friend_button"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/usernameFriendsResource"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:text="Accept"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:background="@drawable/buttons2"
            android:textAllCaps="false"    
            >

        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel_friend_button"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/accept_friend_button"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:background="@drawable/buttons2"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            >

        </Button>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also this the code of the friendsAdapter class:

```
package com.example.online_chat.Adapters

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.online_chat.Models.Users
import com.example.online_chat.R
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView

class FriendAdapter(private var mContext: Context,private var mUsers: List<Users>,private var isChatChecked:Boolean):RecyclerView.Adapter<FriendAdapter.ViewHolder?>() {

    private var currentState:String?=""
    private lateinit var mAuth:FirebaseAuth
    private var firebaseUserId:String=""

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view=LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.user_friends,parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val users=mUsers[position]
        holder.usernameFriend!!.text=users.getUsername()
        holder.fullNameFriend!!.text=users.getFullName()
        Picasso.get().load(users.getProfile()).into(holder.profileImageFriend)
        mAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        firebaseUserId=mAuth.currentUser!!.uid

       
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mUsers.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        var usernameFriend:TextView?=itemView.findViewById(R.id.usernameFriendsResource)
        var fullNameFriend:TextView?=itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_message_friends_ressource)
        var profileImageFriend:CircleImageView?=itemView.findViewById(R.id.friendsProfileResource)
        var acceptBtn: Button?=itemView.findViewById(R.id.accept_friend_button)
        var cancelBtn:Button?=itemView.findViewById(R.id.cancel_friend_button)

    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: First of all, your code is a little hard to read, im sure you can improve this. I think you are not fetching friends_requests from firebase but just users. Therefore request_type key is not present in your fetched data

Comment: How can i do this to fetch for each user the friends requests i am stuck in this problem 2 days i am grateful if you could help me

Comment: i think you should add more info to your friends Requests collection, such as user name and whatever you want to show at the recycler view. Then you can filter that collection for the current user and show Friends Request data at the list. Tell me if you need some code

Comment: I add it in the attached layout xml code in the a above code and attach it it to an adapter class but the main problem is in the friends  fragment when i want to retrieve all the friends requests one by one can someone check my friends fragment code plz?thank you!

Comment: i have edit it and added the code of the friendsAdapter you can check it @javierCuervas

Comment: you are able to see rows in recycler but not data? or recycler does not show anything?

Comment: it does not show anything and in the logcat it says always "no adapter attached ;skipped layout" @rajan.kali

Comment: @javierCuervas i am grateful if you give some code if you can Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this condition is working?

if (p0.child(firebaseUserId).child(users.getUid().toString()).child("request_type").value=="received") && p0.child(users.getUid().toString()).child(firebaseUserId).child("request_type").value=="sent")

You have requested users collection, but no friends request collection. What i think is that your friends request list is just empty and your adapter is never instantiated

I think it would be something like this, please note that there are some pseudo code, as you are using kotlin you should use coroutines to organize this logic for better understanding.

```
FriendAdapter(it,mUsers as ArrayList<Users>,false)

 usersRef.addValueEventListener( DataSnapshot ->
    mUsers?.clear()
    for (snapshot in p0.children) {
      val user: Users? = snapshot.getValue(Users::class.java)
      // check that reference 
      val requestRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://online-chat-541f3-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com").reference.child("Friends Requests/" + user.getId()) 
      // this is pseudo code
      requestRef.addValueEventListener( friendsdataSnapshot -> 
      for (friend if friendsDataSnapshot) {
          //addFriend to mUsersList 
       }
       friendAdapter = context?.let {
           FriendAdapter(it, mUsers as ArrayList<Users>, false)
       }
       friendAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
       recyclerView1!!.adapter = friendAdapter
  )
```